# Source for Sukkos as Sheva Brachos

Tags: yom-kippur, sukkot, drush, sheva-brachos

I once heard from a Rav giving a drasha that "Yom Kippur is the wedding and Sukkos is the Sheva Brachos".

I was wondering what the source for that is?

(The idea of Yom Kippur as a wedding is rather common ביום חתנותו זו מתן תורה, I have seen that referenced as Yom Kippur - but I am wondering primarily about the Sukkos part, although it is possible that the source puts the two together like that drasha did).

Comment: Perhaps related to the second set of seven days at the Chnukat Beit Hamikdash of Shlomo?

Answer (score 1):

[This article by Rav Yona Ziskind](http://www.shearim.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=39&Itemid=34) says:

> Rav Shimshon Pincus writes that the sholosh regolim (the three
>   festivals), Pesach, Shavuos and Succos, are the developmental stages
>   of the Jewish nation. Pesach is the birth of the nation, Shavuos is
>   the bar-mitzvah of the nation and Succos is the chasunah (marriage) of
>   the nation.

I have not yet located the statement in the writing of Rav Pincus.

Comment: It's in the Derashot on Pesach. Don't have the sefer in front of me to give exact page.

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbi Nebenzahl](https://sites.google.com/site/rabbinebenzahl/holidays/5961) mentions this:

> על כל התהליך הזה אפשר למשול משל: שידוך בין איש לאישה. חודש אלול מסמל את תקופת השידוך הראשונה בה מכירים אחד את השני. ראש השנה הוא יום הקידושין בו הקב"ה מקדש את כנסת ישראל וכנסת ישראל מכריזה עליו למלך. יום כיפור הוא יום הנישואין, " 'יום חתונתו' זה מתן תורה" (תענית כו:) יום בו ניתנו למשה רבנו הלוחות האחרונות. השמחה הגדולה שביום כניסתם לחופה היא רק ההתחלה, לאחר מכן באים שבעת ימי המשתה, שבע ברכות, שבזמן חז"ל היו עושים חופה בכל יום מהם. החופה היא הסוכה.‏